# Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'ID'. Table: 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.BidTo'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Up until this morning this problem did not exist. Now, however, when I try to insert into a table with an identity field that is not the primary key I get the above error.

Configuration:

```
    public BidToConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("BidTo");

        HasKey(bt => new { bt.BidRecipientCode, bt.ProposalNumber });

        Property(bt => bt.Awarded)
            .IsOptional();
        Property(bt => bt.BidRecipientCode)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(10);
        Property(bt => bt.BidValue)
            .IsRequired();
        Property(bt => bt.ContactEmail)
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(150);
        Property(bt => bt.ContactName)
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(150);
        Property(bt => bt.ContactPhone)
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(25);
        Property(bt => bt.ID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(bt => bt.LastChanged)
            .IsRequired();
        Property(bt => bt.LastChangedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(bt => bt.ProposalNumber)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15);
        Property(bt => bt.ReqForBidNumber)
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        HasRequired(bt => bt.BidRecipient)
            .WithMany(br => br.BidTos)
            .HasForeignKey(bt => bt.BidRecipientCode);
    }
```

Insert into this table:

```
                    BidTo newBidTo = new BidTo();

                    newBidTo.Awarded = bt.Awarded;
                    newBidTo.BidRecipientCode = bt.BidRecipientCode;
                    newBidTo.BidValue = bt.BidValue;
                    newBidTo.ContactEmail = bt.ContactEmail;
                    newBidTo.ContactName = bt.ContactName;
                    newBidTo.ContactPhone = bt.ContactPhone;
                    newBidTo.ID = bt.ID;
                    newBidTo.LastChanged = DateTime.Now;
                    newBidTo.LastChangedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    newBidTo.ProposalNumber = proposal.ProposalNumber;
                    newBidTo.ReqForBidNumber = bt.ReqForBidNumber;

                    _dbpm.BidTos.Add(newBidTo);
```

When I execute the context.SaveChanges() I get the error regardless if I have the line "newBidTo.ID = bt.ID;" commented out or not.

ADDED: One note, this table, but not the other two with the same error has an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE Trigger.

Comment: You say this just started giving errors today, but the identity columns have been there for a while?  Any idea what might have changed (other than your code)?

Comment: Actually my code didn't change before the error. I thought it needed to change after we received the error. I looked at the Windows Update logs on the web server and the sql server and nothing today.

Comment: I reordered my Linq to SQL statements and the issue went away. I think I was confusing Entity Framework by deleting a record and then adding it back without saving the changes first.